# How can i reflesh select dropdown list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a project on php laravel and react. I have 2 dropdown list in react and they are connected after select first dropdownlist second will be loading from API request. I populated lists with states but whenever i `setState()` page is re-render and every selectments are reseted. I tried this to prevent re-render:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.segment_right !== nextState.segment_right) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

it stop re-render but dropdown list doesn't populate.

this my select dropdown:

```
{['segments'].map(key => (
<Select
    key="segment_2"
    size="large"
    showSearch
    style={{width: '100%', marginTop: 16, borderRadius: 0}}
    placeholder="Segment Seçiniz"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={() => {
    }}
    filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}>
    {this.state.segment_right.map(({[key]: value}) =>
        <Select.Option key={value} value={value}>{value}</Select.Option>)}
</Select>
))}
```

So is there a way to reload dropdown list for populate items without re-render ?

Comment: whenever state variable changes, your component will update. If component doesn't update, your state variable changes won't be reflected. BTW what is the problem with rerender of specific component if that component is purely and and dependent of only those state changes?

Comment: I have 2 select dropdown. I populate them with 2 APIs. when first select has selected, in `onChange` function; the second select dropdown calls api and populate options.  But when populate it causes re-render due to `setState` fucntion. And all selected options are reseted.

Comment: I suggest using separate components for two dropdowns, both using some base options and styling, but having separate logic for data fetching and state setting

Comment: I know but i am asking is there an another way ?

Comment: You can also maintain selected value in state variable for both the dropdowns, that way even if your component renders, your state variable will be preserved and selected value from state can set your select component with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.segment_right !== nextState.segment_right) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

hence your preventing render so drop down options are not populating

solution: you may store the first select box value in state and place that to **defaultValue**

i don't have your full code structure so your code may become like bellow

```
onChange=(e)=>{
  this.setState({
    value:e.target.value
   })
}


{['segments'].map(key => (
<Select
    key="segment_2"
    size="large"
    // append state value to default value and onChange event
    defaultValue={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    showSearch
    style={{width: '100%', marginTop: 16, borderRadius: 0}}
    placeholder="Segment Seçiniz"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={() => {
    }}
    filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}>
    {this.state.segment_right.map(({[key]: value}) =>
        <Select.Option key={value} value={value}>{value}</Select.Option>)}
</Select>
))}
```

please go through with this link [example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lr3m7wrn19) or refer bellow code there second select box value changing with first select box

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: undefined,
      loading: false,
      count: []
    };
  }

  onFirstSelect = e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        loading: true,
        value: value
      },
      //call the api and
      () => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          count: [value, 1]
        });
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      !this.state.loading && (
        <div className="App">
          <select onChange={this.onFirstSelect} defaultValue={this.state.value}>
            <option>slect value</option>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
            <option value="d">d</option>
          </select>
          <select>
            <option>slect value</option>
            {this.state.count.map(d => <option value={d}>{d}</option>)}
          </select>
        </div>
      )
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem with deafultValue Function